# PGP: Checking filetype and returning the extension using windows' FileSign.txt

Tags: c#, pgp

I am actually looking for things like this:

EncryptedFile.pgp ----decryption---> DecryptedFile(no extension) ----use some checking methods----> DecryptedFile.extension

I know that there are alot of people that are asking the similar questions, but those are not the answers/solutions that i am looking for, i had tried them though, none seems to be what i needed.

In windows, when u use command prompt to check files, "filetype Test.txt" it will check the first few byte to determine the file extension/type. It will also create a FileSign.txt file somewhere(maybe desktop or c drive) and the text files contains signature like these:

```
0001000000120100000400204C54534891908748, TTF, "True Type Font";
49443303,MP3,"Compressed Sound";
5249464610C810,AVI,"Audio Video Interleave (AVI) File";
524946462A38000057415645666D74,WAV,"Wave Audio File";
818102000200070104,AVB,"MS Chat Character";
81810300020007010400,BGB,"MS Chat Background File";
3B2068656C702E687066,HPF,"HP LaserJet Fonts";
4C44425800010100000000200000,LDB,"Internet Log File (Zone Alarm)";
5456444227,LOG,"Zone Alarm Data File";
9901A2043C,PKR,"PGP Public Key-ring File";
3C68746D6C3E0D0A3C62,PLG,"MS Developer Build Log";
9501CF0436,SKR,"PGP Secret Key-ring File";
74576263000000000000,SYD,"QEMM / Sysedit Backup File";
535A4444,??_,"MS Compress 5 File(?? Could be anything)";
4B57414A,??_,"MS Compress 6 File(?? Could be anything)";
60EA,ARJ,"ARJ Archive File";
424147,BAG,"BAG Archive";
425A68,BZ,"Bzip Archive File";
4D534346,CAB,"Microsoft Cabinet File";
4D4D5320,CKIT,"Commodore Compressed File";
303730373037,CPIO,"CPIO Archive File";
4352555348,CRU,"CRUSH Archive File";
4841,HA,"HA Archive File";
91334846,HAP,"HAP Archive File";
28546869732066696C65,HQX,"Mac BinHex";
5F27A889,JAR,"Jar Archive File";
2D6C68352D,LHA,"LHA Compressed File";
4D415243,MARC,"MS Archive File";
4D48574B,MHK,"Broderbund Mohawk Archive Format";
4453,Q,"Quantum Archive";
526172211A0700CF9073,RAR,"RAR Compressed File";
EDABEEDB,RPM,"Redhat Linux Archive";
53495421,SIT,"Stuffit v1 Archive File";
53747566664974,SIT,"Stuffit v5 Archive File";
484C53515A,SQZ,"SQZ Archive File";
417070204E616D6509,STF,"ShrinkToFit Compressed Archive";
554641,UFA,"UFA Archive File";
7863722046696C65,XCR,"XCR Archive File";
504B0304140000000800,ZIP,"Winzip 8.1";
504B3030504B0304,ZIP,"WINZIP Compressed";
5A4F4F20,ZOO,"ZOO Compressed File";
2E736E64,AU,"SoundMachine Audio File";
49424B1A,IBK,"Soundblaster Instrument Bank";
4D503344415441,M3D,"MPEG Audio Datafile";
4D546864,MID,"Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) File";
2E7261FD,RAM,"Real Audio File";
2E524D46,RM,"Real Media File";
5354455645024880,SND,"AU Format Sound";
437265617469766520566F6963652046696C651A,VOC,"Creative Sound File";
3B0D0A3B,ASM,"Uncompiled Assembly Code";
0000000C000000,ATN,"Adobe Photoshop Script";
406563686F206F66660D,BTM,"NDOS Batch to Memory";
23212F62696E2F73680A,CGI,"Common Gateway Interface Script";
2F2A202A202A202A202A,H,"C++ Header File";
484FF3C976332E39392E,OBS,"ObjectScript";
56435043483000000000,PCH,"MS C++  Precompiled Header File";
00000100000001480000,RSC,"Compiled Resources";
DCFE,EFX,"eFax file format";
0363080A,DBF,"Database File";
000100005374616E6461,MDB,"Microsoft Access file";
4D4C42,MLB,"MyLittleBase Database File";
00000041424300000000,ABC,"Micrografx ABC Flowcharter";
5157205665722E20,ABD,"Quicken Data File";
30000004150505,ADX,"Lotus Approach ADX File";
252150532D41646F6265,AI,"Adobe Illustrator";
5B7665725D,AMI,"Lotus Ami Pro";
5008,APP,"Clarion File Format";
49545346030000006000,CHM,"Compiled HTML Help File";
464158434F5645,CPE,"MS Office Fax Cover";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 10 Office 2000 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 8.0 Office 97 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Generic MS Office File";
504B0304140000000000,DOC,"Star Writer 6.0";
31BE000000AB0000,DOC,"MS Word for DOS v6 File";
1234567890FF,DOC,"MS Word 6.0 File";
7FFE340A,DOC,"MS Word File";
4D47582069747064,DS4,"Micrografix Designer 4";
4D5600FF0C0010000000,DST,"Micrografx Designer Template";
3C21454E54495459,DTD,"Xml DTD";
C5D0D3C6,EPS,"Adobe Encapsulated PostScript File";
00001A0007800100,FM3,"Lotus 123 v3 FMT File";
2000680020,FMT,"Lotus 123 v4 FMT File";
3C68746D6C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 1 File";
3C48544D4C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 2 File";
3C21444F4354,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 3 File";
000100004D534953414D204461746162617365,MNY,"Microsoft Money File";
1A0000030000,NSF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
1A000003000011000100,NTF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
255044462D312E320D0A25E2E3CF,PDF,"PDF-1.2";
AC9EBD8F,QDF,"Quicken Data File";
5157205665722E20,QSD,"Quicken Data File";
7B5C727466,RTF,"Rich Text Format";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1000000000000,SDW,"Star Writer 3 - 5";
C354565362BD8AFF0000,TV4,"WordPerfect Insert Overflow - Doc 4";
2000604060,WK1,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
00001A0000100400,WK3,"Lotus 123 v3 Worksheet";
00001A0002100400,WK4,"Lotus 123 v5";
00001A001004,WKS,"Lotus MS Worksheet";
2000604060,WKS,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
FF575043,WP,"WordPerfect v5 or v6";
090808000005000433,XLB,"Microsoft Excel Workbook";
0904060000004000,XLM,"Microsoft Excel Macro";
0902060000001000B9045C00,XLS,"MS Excel v2";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 2 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 1 File";
0904060000001000F6055C00,XLS,"MS Excel v4 File";
FFFE3C0052004F004F00540053005400550042,XML,"MS Excel Document";
3C3F786D6C,XML,"MS Excel XML Document";
3D02,3D2,"Stereo CAD-3D 2 File";
33444D46,3DMF,"3D Meta File";
2A2A544939322A2A0100586E5669,92I,"TI Bitmap";
414D4646,AMFF,"AMFF Image File";
4A47040E000000,ART,"AOL ART 1";
4A47030E000000,ART,"AOL ART 2";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Generic File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 1 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 2 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 3 File";
BB010001C800C80001,BRK/301,"Brooktrout Fax";
737263646F6369643A,CALS,"CALS Raster Image";
07204D4D,CAM,"QV-10 Camera File";
20770002,CBD,"Vector Map Data Format";
45594553,CE2,"Computer Eyes File";
802A5FD700000800000004000000,CIN,"Kodac Cineon";
43616C6967617269,COB,"Caligari Truespace 2 File";
43505446494C45,CPT,"Corel Photopaint";
43414C414D5553435647,CVG,"Calamus";
3ADE68B1,DCX,"DCX Graphic File";
56697374612044454D2046696C65,DEM,"Vista Landscape Format";
424D36,DIB,"DIB Image File";
53445058,DPX,"Cineon Image File";
01FF02040302,DRW,"Micrographx Graphic";
41433130,DWG,"Autocad R13/R14 File";
65020102,ECW,"Enhanced Compressed Wavelet";
0100000058000000,EMF,"Enhanced Metafile Graphic";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE100,FPX,"FlashPix";
53494D504C4520203D,FTS,"Flexible Image Transport System";
47494638,GIF,"ALL Types";
4850485034382D451E2B,GRO,"HP-48/49 GROB";
6E636F6C73,HDR,"ArcoInfo Binary Image";
354B5035315D2A67727280838563,HRU,"HRU Image";
EB3C902A,IMG,"GEM Raster file";
656C6D6F,INFINI-D,"Infini-D Graphics File";
49574301,IWC,"WaveL Image";
803E445343494D,J6I,"Ricoh Camera Image File";
4A4946393961,JIF,"Jeff's Image Format";
0000000C6A5020200D0A870A,JP2,"JPEG-2000 JP2 Image";
FFD8FFE1,JPG,"Generic 1 JPG";
FFD8FFE0,JPG,"Generic 2 JPG";
FFD8FFE14ED84578696600004949,JPG,"Kodak";
4D4D002A,KDC,"Kodak Camera DC20/40/50";
36344C414E204944424C4F434B,L64,"64LAN Image File";
464F524D,LBM,"Interchange File";
49492A00080000000E0000010400,LDF,"LuraDocument Format";
575602004745000E,LWF,"LuraWave Format";
3700001042000010000000003964,MBM,"Psion Series 5 Bitmap";
4D474C,MGL,"MosASCII Graphics Library File";
7B0A202043726561746564,MIF,"Image Magick File";
8A4D4E470D0A1A0A,MNG,"Multiple Image Format";
4D5046,MPW,"MosASCII Project Workspace File";
44616E4D,MSP,"Windows Paint File";
433634,N64,"64NET Image File";
6E6E0A005E00,NCR,"NCR G4";
6E6666,NFF,"WorldToolKit Neutral File Format";
4E4747000100,NGG,"Nokia Group Graphics";
4E4C4D20010200,NLM,"Nokia Logo File";
4E4F4C00010006010300,NOL,"Nokia Operator Logo";
4148,PAL,"Dr. Halo Palette File";
0000002000000001,PAT,"Gimp Pattern";
504158,PAX,"Secure Image File";
50340A,PBM,"Portable Bitmap";
6352010138093D00,PCD,"Kodak PhotoCD";
1B451B266C304F1B266C30451B26,PCL,"Page Control Language";
0A050108,PCX,"PC Paintbrush";
5032,PGM,"Portable Greymap File";
50350A,PGM,"Portable Greyscale";
5380F6344020,PIC,"Softimage";
504943DC30300100,PIC,"Psion Series 3 Bitmap";
9119,PIC,"PIC File";
50495820,PIX,"PABX Background";
89504E470D0A1A0A,PNG,"Portable Network Graphic";
889A0D12,PNG,"Portable Network Graphics File";
504F4C20466F726D6174,POL,"Polygon Model File";
5033,PPM,"Portable Pixmap File";
38425053000100000000,PSD,"Adobe PhotoShop";
7E424B00,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
5061696E742053686F702050726F20496D6167652046696C65,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
514C4949464158,QFX,"Fax Image File";
6D6F6F76,QTM,"Apple Quick Time File";
464F524D41543D,RAD,"Radiance";
59A66A95,RAS,"SUN Raster File";
01DA01010003,RGB,"Silicon Graphics RGB";
52495833,RIX,"ColoRIX File";
23202449643A20,SID,"Seamless Image Graphic File";
4175746F43414420536C696465,SLD,"Slide Library File";
53746F726D3344,SOD,"Storm 3D Object Definition";
49492A00,TIFF,"TIFF Image File";
4D4D2A,TIF,"TIF Image File (Motorola)";
FADEBABE0101,WIC,"J Wavelet Image Codec";
D323000003000000,WLM,"CompW Image";
D7CDC69A,WMF,"Windows graphics metafile";
FF57504310,WPG,"WordPerfect Graphic";
2356524D4C2056322E30,WRL,"VRML Version 2 Image";
23646566696E65,XBM,"XBM - X11 Bitmap";
2F2A2058504D202A2F,XPM,"XPM - X11 Pixmap";
436C69656E742055726C43616368,DAT,"IE History DAT File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
5B50686F6E655D,DUN,"Dial-Up Network Export File";
CFAD12FEC5FD,DBX,"Outlook Express Email Storage File";
3C21646F63747970652068746D6C207075626C6963,DCI,"AOL Web Email";
52657475726E2D506174683A203C,EML,"Outlook Express Email Message";
46726F6D202D20,EML,"Netscape Email Message";
46726F6D203F3F3F403F3F3F20,EML,"Eudora Email Message";
46726F6D3A20,EML,"Generic Email Message";
2142444E,PST,"Outlook 97 File";
0006156100000002000004D20000,HST,"Netscape HST";
574542,IGY,"Web Query";
5745420D0A310D0A687474703A2F,IQY,"Microsoft Web Query";
5F434153455F,CAS,"EnCase Case (or Backup) File";
FEEF01,GHO,"Norton Ghost Image File";
43363453207461706520696D6167652066696C65,T64,"C64 Tape Image";
43363420434152545249444745,CRT,"C64 Emul Cartridge File";
BABEEBEA,ANI,"NEOchrome Animation File";
4C504620,ANM,"DeluxePaint Animation";
3026B2758E66CF11A6D900AA0062,ASF,"Windows Media (ASF Compression)";
56445649,AVS,"Intel Digital Video Interface File";
44564D,DVM,"DVM Movie File";
52414E44,Filmstrip,"Adobe Filmstrip File Format";
AF12,FLC,"Animator Pro Flic Files";
494D4443,IC3,"Atari Image Film";
4C5A414E494D,LZA,"Lempel-Ziv-Oberhumer Compressed Animation";
07010100436F70797269,MMM,"Microsoft Media Clip";
000007B56D6F6F76,MOV,"QuickTime Movie File";
6D646174,QT,"Quick Time Movie File";
000001B3,MPEG,"MPEG Video File";
5E405C6E534D4A504547,SMJPEG,"Simple Animation File";
B5A2B0B3B3B0A2B5,CAL,"Windows 3.1 Calendar";
52545353,CAP,"Windows NT Netmon Capture File";
4D53434600000000,CDM,"Windows Update File";
50C30100080028,CLP,"Windows Clipboard File";
43524547,DAT,"Windows 95 Registry Files";
5348434333,DAT,"Windows 3.1 Registry File (REG.DAT)";
202020202020696E7465,FON,"Font File";
3F5F0300,GID,"General Index";
504D4343,GRP,"MS Windows Group";
3F5F0300,HLP,"Windows Help File";
4C4E0200,HLP,"Windows Help File";
48797065725465726D69,HT,"HyperTerminal File";
5B4578745368656C6C466F6C6465,INI,"Desktop.ini Folder Setting File";
47040100,JOB,"Scheduled Tasks File";
7B0D0A6F206331,LGC,"Application Log File";
4C00000001140200,LNK,"Windows Shortcut File";
4C5441520001,LTR,"Letter File";
2A5050442D41646F6265,PPD,"Postscript Printer Description File";
E3828596010000,PWL,"Windows Password File";
5245474544495434,REG,"Windows NT Registry File";
0D0A5B536865,SCF,"Shell Command File";
3B0D0A3B205468697320697320,SCP,"Dial-Up Network Script";
6749000078,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
4B490000,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
5245474544495434,SUD,"Registry Undo Files";
FF4B455942202020,SYS,"Keyboard driver file";
4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF,EXE,"Acrobat plugin, Executable, Screen Saver";
504B030414000600080000002100710E,XLSX,"MSExcel 2007 Document";
504B030414000600080000002100DDFC,DOCX,"MSWord 2007 Document";
7B5C72746631,RTF,"Rich Text File";
377ABCAF271C0003838E304BB97F,7z, "7z Compressed File";
FEFF,txt, "UTF-16 Big Endian text file";
FFFE,txt, "UTF-16 Little Endian text file";
EFBBBF,txt, "UTF-8 text file";
377ABCAF271C0003,7z, "7z Archive File";
504B03041400000800000FB6913D5EC6320C27,odt, "OpenOffice Document Text";
6162432C3132330D0A0000000000000000000000,CSV, "Comma Seperate Value File";
504B0304140,odp,"Open Office Presentation";
,,;
```

Is it possible to use this FileSign.txt to check and return the correct extension?

codes: blahblahblah

output(on a TextBox):

```
.exe
```

Thanks!!! really need help on this one.

Comment: When I type `filetype /?` from a command prompt (Windows 7 64-bit), it says "'filetype' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.".

Comment: Did you try to use the command instead of using /?. Maybe its my mistake, this might not be a windows command.

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem. The original filename with the extension is usually stored in (inside of) the OpenPGP file.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you. u mean the original filename and extension is within the EncryptedFile.pgp? If that is the case, how to i decrypt them with the original extension? The filename is not of importance. More priority for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public string getFileType(String filePath) {
    string retFileInfo = "";
    try {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        int hexIn;
        string hex = "";
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++) {
            if (counter >= 15) break;
            else hex += string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
            counter++;
        }
        fs.Close();
        counter = 0;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\AwaisKing\\Desktop\\FileSigs.txt");
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            line = line.Replace(";", "");
            string[] spInfo = line.Split(',');
            if (hex.StartsWith(spInfo[0])) {
                retFileInfo = spInfo[1] + " - " + spInfo[2];
                file.Close();
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    file.Close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e.Message;
    }
    return retFileInfo;
}
```

and my signatures file (**FileSigs.txt**):

```
0001000000120100000400204C54534891908748, TTF, "True Type Font";
49443303,MP3,"Compressed Sound";
5249464610C810,AVI,"Audio Video Interleave (AVI) File";
524946462A38000057415645666D74,WAV,"Wave Audio File";
818102000200070104,AVB,"MS Chat Character";
81810300020007010400,BGB,"MS Chat Background File";
3B2068656C702E687066,HPF,"HP LaserJet Fonts";
4C44425800010100000000200000,LDB,"Internet Log File (Zone Alarm)";
5456444227,LOG,"Zone Alarm Data File";
9901A2043C,PKR,"PGP Public Key-ring File";
3C68746D6C3E0D0A3C62,PLG,"MS Developer Build Log";
9501CF0436,SKR,"PGP Secret Key-ring File";
74576263000000000000,SYD,"QEMM / Sysedit Backup File";
535A4444,??_,"MS Compress 5 File(?? Could be anything)";
4B57414A,??_,"MS Compress 6 File(?? Could be anything)";
60EA,ARJ,"ARJ Archive File";
424147,BAG,"BAG Archive";
425A68,BZ,"Bzip Archive File";
4D534346,CAB,"Microsoft Cabinet File";
4D4D5320,CKIT,"Commodore Compressed File";
303730373037,CPIO,"CPIO Archive File";
4352555348,CRU,"CRUSH Archive File";
4841,HA,"HA Archive File";
91334846,HAP,"HAP Archive File";
28546869732066696C65,HQX,"Mac BinHex";
5F27A889,JAR,"Jar Archive File";
2D6C68352D,LHA,"LHA Compressed File";
4D415243,MARC,"MS Archive File";
4D48574B,MHK,"Broderbund Mohawk Archive Format";
4453,Q,"Quantum Archive";
526172211A0700CF9073,RAR,"RAR Compressed File";
EDABEEDB,RPM,"Redhat Linux Archive";
53495421,SIT,"Stuffit v1 Archive File";
53747566664974,SIT,"Stuffit v5 Archive File";
484C53515A,SQZ,"SQZ Archive File";
417070204E616D6509,STF,"ShrinkToFit Compressed Archive";
554641,UFA,"UFA Archive File";
7863722046696C65,XCR,"XCR Archive File";
504B0304140000000800,ZIP,"Winzip 8.1";
504B3030504B0304,ZIP,"WINZIP Compressed";
5A4F4F20,ZOO,"ZOO Compressed File";
2E736E64,AU,"SoundMachine Audio File";
49424B1A,IBK,"Soundblaster Instrument Bank";
4D503344415441,M3D,"MPEG Audio Datafile";
4D546864,MID,"Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) File";
2E7261FD,RAM,"Real Audio File";
2E524D46,RM,"Real Media File";
5354455645024880,SND,"AU Format Sound";
437265617469766520566F6963652046696C651A,VOC,"Creative Sound File";
3B0D0A3B,ASM,"Uncompiled Assembly Code";
0000000C000000,ATN,"Adobe Photoshop Script";
406563686F206F66660D,BTM,"NDOS Batch to Memory";
23212F62696E2F73680A,CGI,"Common Gateway Interface Script";
2F2A202A202A202A202A,H,"C++ Header File";
484FF3C976332E39392E,OBS,"ObjectScript";
56435043483000000000,PCH,"MS C++  Precompiled Header File";
00000100000001480000,RSC,"Compiled Resources";
DCFE,EFX,"eFax file format";
0363080A,DBF,"Database File";
000100005374616E6461,MDB,"Microsoft Access file";
4D4C42,MLB,"MyLittleBase Database File";
00000041424300000000,ABC,"Micrografx ABC Flowcharter";
5157205665722E20,ABD,"Quicken Data File";
30000004150505,ADX,"Lotus Approach ADX File";
252150532D41646F6265,AI,"Adobe Illustrator";
5B7665725D,AMI,"Lotus Ami Pro";
5008,APP,"Clarion File Format";
49545346030000006000,CHM,"Compiled HTML Help File";
464158434F5645,CPE,"MS Office Fax Cover";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 10 Office 2000 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 8.0 Office 97 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Generic MS Office File";
504B0304140000000000,DOC,"Star Writer 6.0";
31BE000000AB0000,DOC,"MS Word for DOS v6 File";
1234567890FF,DOC,"MS Word 6.0 File";
7FFE340A,DOC,"MS Word File";
4D47582069747064,DS4,"Micrografix Designer 4";
4D5600FF0C0010000000,DST,"Micrografx Designer Template";
3C21454E54495459,DTD,"Xml DTD";
C5D0D3C6,EPS,"Adobe Encapsulated PostScript File";
00001A0007800100,FM3,"Lotus 123 v3 FMT File";
2000680020,FMT,"Lotus 123 v4 FMT File";
3C68746D6C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 1 File";
3C48544D4C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 2 File";
3C21444F4354,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 3 File";
000100004D534953414D204461746162617365,MNY,"Microsoft Money File";
1A0000030000,NSF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
1A000003000011000100,NTF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
255044462D312E320D0A25E2E3CF,PDF,"PDF-1.2";
AC9EBD8F,QDF,"Quicken Data File";
5157205665722E20,QSD,"Quicken Data File";
7B5C727466,RTF,"Rich Text Format";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1000000000000,SDW,"Star Writer 3 - 5";
C354565362BD8AFF0000,TV4,"WordPerfect Insert Overflow - Doc 4";
2000604060,WK1,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
00001A0000100400,WK3,"Lotus 123 v3 Worksheet";
00001A0002100400,WK4,"Lotus 123 v5";
00001A001004,WKS,"Lotus MS Worksheet";
2000604060,WKS,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
FF575043,WP,"WordPerfect v5 or v6";
090808000005000433,XLB,"Microsoft Excel Workbook";
0904060000004000,XLM,"Microsoft Excel Macro";
0902060000001000B9045C00,XLS,"MS Excel v2";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 2 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 1 File";
0904060000001000F6055C00,XLS,"MS Excel v4 File";
FFFE3C0052004F004F00540053005400550042,XML,"MS Excel Document";
3C3F786D6C,XML,"MS Excel XML Document";
3D02,3D2,"Stereo CAD-3D 2 File";
33444D46,3DMF,"3D Meta File";
2A2A544939322A2A0100586E5669,92I,"TI Bitmap";
414D4646,AMFF,"AMFF Image File";
4A47040E000000,ART,"AOL ART 1";
4A47030E000000,ART,"AOL ART 2";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Generic File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 1 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 2 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 3 File";
BB010001C800C80001,BRK/301,"Brooktrout Fax";
737263646F6369643A,CALS,"CALS Raster Image";
07204D4D,CAM,"QV-10 Camera File";
20770002,CBD,"Vector Map Data Format";
45594553,CE2,"Computer Eyes File";
802A5FD700000800000004000000,CIN,"Kodac Cineon";
43616C6967617269,COB,"Caligari Truespace 2 File";
43505446494C45,CPT,"Corel Photopaint";
43414C414D5553435647,CVG,"Calamus";
3ADE68B1,DCX,"DCX Graphic File";
56697374612044454D2046696C65,DEM,"Vista Landscape Format";
424D36,DIB,"DIB Image File";
53445058,DPX,"Cineon Image File";
01FF02040302,DRW,"Micrographx Graphic";
41433130,DWG,"Autocad R13/R14 File";
65020102,ECW,"Enhanced Compressed Wavelet";
0100000058000000,EMF,"Enhanced Metafile Graphic";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE100,FPX,"FlashPix";
53494D504C4520203D,FTS,"Flexible Image Transport System";
47494638,GIF,"ALL Types";
4850485034382D451E2B,GRO,"HP-48/49 GROB";
6E636F6C73,HDR,"ArcoInfo Binary Image";
354B5035315D2A67727280838563,HRU,"HRU Image";
EB3C902A,IMG,"GEM Raster file";
656C6D6F,INFINI-D,"Infini-D Graphics File";
49574301,IWC,"WaveL Image";
803E445343494D,J6I,"Ricoh Camera Image File";
4A4946393961,JIF,"Jeff's Image Format";
0000000C6A5020200D0A870A,JP2,"JPEG-2000 JP2 Image";
FFD8FFE1,JPG,"Generic 1 JPG";
FFD8FFE0,JPG,"Generic 2 JPG";
FFD8FFE14ED84578696600004949,JPG,"Kodak";
4D4D002A,KDC,"Kodak Camera DC20/40/50";
36344C414E204944424C4F434B,L64,"64LAN Image File";
464F524D,LBM,"Interchange File";
49492A00080000000E0000010400,LDF,"LuraDocument Format";
575602004745000E,LWF,"LuraWave Format";
3700001042000010000000003964,MBM,"Psion Series 5 Bitmap";
4D474C,MGL,"MosASCII Graphics Library File";
7B0A202043726561746564,MIF,"Image Magick File";
8A4D4E470D0A1A0A,MNG,"Multiple Image Format";
4D5046,MPW,"MosASCII Project Workspace File";
44616E4D,MSP,"Windows Paint File";
433634,N64,"64NET Image File";
6E6E0A005E00,NCR,"NCR G4";
6E6666,NFF,"WorldToolKit Neutral File Format";
4E4747000100,NGG,"Nokia Group Graphics";
4E4C4D20010200,NLM,"Nokia Logo File";
4E4F4C00010006010300,NOL,"Nokia Operator Logo";
4148,PAL,"Dr. Halo Palette File";
0000002000000001,PAT,"Gimp Pattern";
504158,PAX,"Secure Image File";
50340A,PBM,"Portable Bitmap";
6352010138093D00,PCD,"Kodak PhotoCD";
1B451B266C304F1B266C30451B26,PCL,"Page Control Language";
0A050108,PCX,"PC Paintbrush";
5032,PGM,"Portable Greymap File";
50350A,PGM,"Portable Greyscale";
5380F6344020,PIC,"Softimage";
504943DC30300100,PIC,"Psion Series 3 Bitmap";
9119,PIC,"PIC File";
50495820,PIX,"PABX Background";
89504E470D0A1A0A,PNG,"Portable Network Graphic";
889A0D12,PNG,"Portable Network Graphics File";
504F4C20466F726D6174,POL,"Polygon Model File";
5033,PPM,"Portable Pixmap File";
38425053000100000000,PSD,"Adobe PhotoShop";
7E424B00,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
5061696E742053686F702050726F20496D6167652046696C65,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
514C4949464158,QFX,"Fax Image File";
6D6F6F76,QTM,"Apple Quick Time File";
464F524D41543D,RAD,"Radiance";
59A66A95,RAS,"SUN Raster File";
01DA01010003,RGB,"Silicon Graphics RGB";
52495833,RIX,"ColoRIX File";
23202449643A20,SID,"Seamless Image Graphic File";
4175746F43414420536C696465,SLD,"Slide Library File";
53746F726D3344,SOD,"Storm 3D Object Definition";
49492A00,TIFF,"TIFF Image File";
4D4D2A,TIF,"TIF Image File (Motorola)";
FADEBABE0101,WIC,"J Wavelet Image Codec";
D323000003000000,WLM,"CompW Image";
D7CDC69A,WMF,"Windows graphics metafile";
FF57504310,WPG,"WordPerfect Graphic";
2356524D4C2056322E30,WRL,"VRML Version 2 Image";
23646566696E65,XBM,"XBM - X11 Bitmap";
2F2A2058504D202A2F,XPM,"XPM - X11 Pixmap";
436C69656E742055726C43616368,DAT,"IE History DAT File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
5B50686F6E655D,DUN,"Dial-Up Network Export File";
CFAD12FEC5FD,DBX,"Outlook Express Email Storage File";
3C21646F63747970652068746D6C207075626C6963,DCI,"AOL Web Email";
52657475726E2D506174683A203C,EML,"Outlook Express Email Message";
46726F6D202D20,EML,"Netscape Email Message";
46726F6D203F3F3F403F3F3F20,EML,"Eudora Email Message";
46726F6D3A20,EML,"Generic Email Message";
2142444E,PST,"Outlook 97 File";
0006156100000002000004D20000,HST,"Netscape HST";
574542,IGY,"Web Query";
5745420D0A310D0A687474703A2F,IQY,"Microsoft Web Query";
5F434153455F,CAS,"EnCase Case (or Backup) File";
FEEF01,GHO,"Norton Ghost Image File";
43363453207461706520696D6167652066696C65,T64,"C64 Tape Image";
43363420434152545249444745,CRT,"C64 Emul Cartridge File";
BABEEBEA,ANI,"NEOchrome Animation File";
4C504620,ANM,"DeluxePaint Animation";
3026B2758E66CF11A6D900AA0062,ASF,"Windows Media (ASF Compression)";
56445649,AVS,"Intel Digital Video Interface File";
44564D,DVM,"DVM Movie File";
52414E44,Filmstrip,"Adobe Filmstrip File Format";
AF12,FLC,"Animator Pro Flic Files";
494D4443,IC3,"Atari Image Film";
4C5A414E494D,LZA,"Lempel-Ziv-Oberhumer Compressed Animation";
07010100436F70797269,MMM,"Microsoft Media Clip";
000007B56D6F6F76,MOV,"QuickTime Movie File";
6D646174,QT,"Quick Time Movie File";
000001B3,MPEG,"MPEG Video File";
5E405C6E534D4A504547,SMJPEG,"Simple Animation File";
B5A2B0B3B3B0A2B5,CAL,"Windows 3.1 Calendar";
52545353,CAP,"Windows NT Netmon Capture File";
4D53434600000000,CDM,"Windows Update File";
50C30100080028,CLP,"Windows Clipboard File";
43524547,DAT,"Windows 95 Registry Files";
5348434333,DAT,"Windows 3.1 Registry File (REG.DAT)";
202020202020696E7465,FON,"Font File";
3F5F0300,GID,"General Index";
504D4343,GRP,"MS Windows Group";
3F5F0300,HLP,"Windows Help File";
4C4E0200,HLP,"Windows Help File";
48797065725465726D69,HT,"HyperTerminal File";
5B4578745368656C6C466F6C6465,INI,"Desktop.ini Folder Setting File";
47040100,JOB,"Scheduled Tasks File";
7B0D0A6F206331,LGC,"Application Log File";
4C00000001140200,LNK,"Windows Shortcut File";
4C5441520001,LTR,"Letter File";
2A5050442D41646F6265,PPD,"Postscript Printer Description File";
E3828596010000,PWL,"Windows Password File";
5245474544495434,REG,"Windows NT Registry File";
0D0A5B536865,SCF,"Shell Command File";
3B0D0A3B205468697320697320,SCP,"Dial-Up Network Script";
6749000078,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
4B490000,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
5245474544495434,SUD,"Registry Undo Files";
FF4B455942202020,SYS,"Keyboard driver file";
4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF,EXE,"Acrobat plugin, Executable, Screen Saver";
504B030414000600080000002100710E,XLSX,"MSExcel 2007 Document";
504B030414000600080000002100DDFC,DOCX,"MSWord 2007 Document";
7B5C72746631,RTF,"Rich Text File";
377ABCAF271C0003838E304BB97F,7z, "7z Compressed File";
FEFF,txt, "UTF-16 Big Endian text file";
FFFE,txt, "UTF-16 Little Endian text file";
EFBBBF,txt, "UTF-8 text file";
377ABCAF271C0003,7z, "7z Archive File";
504B03041400000800000FB6913D5EC6320C27,odt, "OpenOffice Document Text";
6162432C3132330D0A0000000000000000000000,CSV, "Comma Seperate Value File";
504B0304140,odp,"Open Office Presentation";
```